# My $scope value not updating

Tags: angularjs

**updated object is not getting without using location.reload**

Hi i will get list of objects from API where i have to update one value,After updating that value in modal popup i am not able to get new  updated value without using location.reload. Is there any other solution for this.i am using two different controllers.

```
Will get list of objects from this
 $scope.groups=response.data
```

will ng-repeat this groups where i will have edit button for every line,Once i click edit button popup will open

```
$scope.editGroup = function(u) {
    $scope.groupName=u.groupName;
    $scope.groupId=u.groupId;
    ModalService.showModal({
        templateUrl: 'app/components/modal/editGroupDetails.html',
        controller: "ModalController",
        scope: $scope
    }).then(function(modal) {
        modal.element.modal();
        modal.close.then(function(result) {

            $scope.message = "You said " + result;
        });
    });
};
```

Next once i edit the GroupName i will click submit

```
$scope.updateGroupName=function(){
                var data={
                "groupId": $scope.groupId,
                "groupName": $scope.groupName
        }
        url=globalUrlConfig.globalAdminApi+globalUrlConfig.updateGroup+$scope.schoolId;
        $http({
            method: 'PUT',
            url: url,
            data: data,
        }).success(function(response) {
            console.log(response)
            if(response._statusCode==200){
                alert(response.data);

                location.reload();
            }
            else{
                alert("not updated")
            }

        })
    }
```

**Without using location.reload i am not able display updated data**

Comment: you have to update the object itself being shown in the view.

Comment: try to change the value which u have updated in  $scope.groups by using a unique value like id,index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$rootscope` like this

Add this `$rootScope.$emit("refreshData", {});`
 instead of `Location.reload();`

And then add this in your main controller for load data without refresh

```
var RefreshValue = $rootScope.$on("refreshData", function () {
             GetValueMethod(); // call your method (List of object) for get data without reload form 
        });
        $scope.$on('$destroy', RefreshValue);
```

**Don't forget to inject `$rootScope`.**